# Purging secret from Azure Key Vault with soft delete enabled

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

While implementing secure app model, we have stored the refresh token in azure key vault as a secret. While reconsent we delete that refresh token and again put the new refresh token.

Previously in azure key vault soft delete was not mandatory,so things were working fine. Now in azure key vault soft delete is mandatory so when I delete the old secret and set new secret with same name I am getting exception "Secret already present with deleted state".

As a solution now after delete secret I call purgeSecret to permanently delete it, but there is again a new problem.

Before purging we need to wait around 20 seconds so that deletedSecret call works properly else purgeSecret throws exception that "Secret is being deleted". and also to make purge successfull we again need to wait for around 10-15 seconds after purge call.

So total aroung 35 seconds we need to wait before I completely remove the old secret and then only I can set new secret.

As per our requirement, we can not wait this much amount of time, and we can not update the secret.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

instead of implementing a wait, can you implement retry in your code logic that handles the exception and then tries again? There will still be a delay, but it shouldn't take 35 seconds to complete.

Comment: retry is also kind of wait... even with retry also its some waiting...any other possibility to avoid it?